# How to use a $watchGroup with object equality or deep-watch the properties in the group?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want a directive to re-render HTML whenever three scope variables have changed. The first two are just integers, the third is an array.

We have `$watchGroup` to watch several variables, we have `$watch` with `objectEquality` as a third parameter, and we have `$watchCollection` which is like `$watch`, but with `objectEquality` implied.

Is there a way to write a `$watch` similar to this?

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['number1', 'number2', 'myArray'], callback, true); // true for objectEquality
```

Comment: I'm using AngularJS 1.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well it seems like watchGroup does not support a deep watch. So probably you can do a hack, by registering an anonymous deep watcher with array of values being passed in from the watch function.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
     return ['number1','number2','myArray'].map(angular.bind($scope, $scope.$eval));
  }, function(newV){
      console.log(newV);
  },true);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/A4vJV8?p=preview)**

or just add this function as utility function on the rootScope and access it from any inherited scopes.

```
.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.deepWatchGroup = function(exp, callback){
    if(!angular.isArray(exp) || !thisScope.$watch) return; //Or log some error if array is not passed in or the context is not really a scope object

   var thisScope = this, //get scope
        evalFunc = angular.bind(thisScope, thisScope.$eval); //and a bound eval func

     thisScope.$watch(function(){
        return exp.map(evalFunc); //return array of evaluated values
     }, callback,true);
   }
});
```

and from your controller do:

```
$scope.deepWatchGroup(['number1','number2','myArray'],function(newV){
  console.log(newV);
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/g6jUFf?p=preview)**

Comment: On my angular 1.3.6, I had to swap out `thisScope` for `this`, and use `$scope.deepWatchGroup.call($scope, ['one' ,'two'], function(newVals){})`. Thanks for the quick tip!

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you were able to get it to work Morgan Delaney?

Comment: Also is there any help on the newest version on Angular. 1.4.x?

Comment: Do you think this solution is performant? The watch expression will run on each digest. Performing a `map` + `$eval` seems a heavy task for it to be called so many times.

Comment: @AlejandroIglesias It is a pretty old answer but you are right :), first of all if you ever manually need to add a watch at all that is where the main problem is- A better design, a more reactive, component oriented design, would avoid creation of manual watchers in the first place. I think that should be the point of optimization.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to watch an array of **string** expressions (i.e. you do not need to watch functions, which both `$watchGroup` and PSL's solution can handle), here is an alternative:

```
$scope.$watch('[number1, number2, myArray]', callback, true);
```

And if you want to make a utility function for that similar to PSL's:

```
.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.deepWatchGroup = function(watchExpressions, listener){
    this.$watch('[' + watchExpressions + ']', listener, true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly with different types of variables.

Comment: Really old, but I just took over an old project we had to modify, and simply updating from $watchGroup to $watch in this fashion, and adding the "true" attribute, worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem as yours.

My solution to this deep watchgroup problem is:

```
// Create new object to watch different types of objects
var objectToBeWatch = {
    number1: number1, 
    number2: number2,
    myArray: myArray
};

$scope.$watch(
    function () {
        return objectToBeWatch;
}, callback, true);
```

I hope this helps!