# How to $watch more than one collection in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two arrays in my application I would like to observe changes:

```
$scope.a = [{id: 1, text: 'test a - 1'}, ...];
$scope.b = [{id: 1, text: 'test b - 1'}, ...];

function changed(){
  // notify application about changes in a or b
}
```

I have to call the `changed()` function when `a` or `b` have been changed.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('a', changed);
$scope.$watchCollection('b', changed);
```

The `changed()` callback will be triggered twice if I have changes in `a` and `b` as well as on init step. I would like to combine two watches in one, something like this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('a, b', changed);
```

How can I do this with Angular?

Comment: Any luck with any of these answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called [`watchGroup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) which you can use for this purpose, But unfortunately is is mostly useless as it does only shallow watch.

You could use the watcher function to return your object

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ //Or even try this with watchCollection
     return ['a','b'].map(angular.bind($scope, $scope.$eval));
  }, function(newV){
      console.log(newV);
  },true);
```

You could instead **[create a custom watcher for your convenience as i had mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712888/how-to-use-a-watchgroup-with-object-equality-or-deep-watch-the-properties-in-th#answer-25713285)** and do something like this.

```
$scope.deepWatchGroup(['a','b'],function(newV){
  console.log(newV);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$scope. $watch('a+b', change)`. You can add any number of variable to watch

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, but I'm not sure that it will work for arrays of objects.

Comment: This looks interesting but i doubt this will work, because a+b will concatinate 2 objects and will result in `[object Object][object Object]", "[object Object][object Object]"` http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2GzAo?p=preview