# Passing an array to $watchGroup and updating the array on change

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, data-binding, watch

## Problem:

I'd like to pass an array of variables into $watchGroup and loop through the array to update the values of each but this does not seem to work:

```
$scope.secondsElapsed = stopWatchService.secondsElapsed;
$scope.minutesElapsed = stopWatchService.minutesElapsed;
$scope.colon = stopWatchService.colon;

$scope.timers = ['stopWatchService.secondsElapsed', 'stopWatchService.minutesElapsed', 'stopWatchService.colon'];

$scope.$watchGroup([$scope.timers], function(newValues, oldValues, scope){
    if (newValues && newValues !== oldValues){
        for (var i=0; i<newValues.length; i++){
            scope.timers[i] = newValues[i];
        }
    }
});
```

The current work around I have is the following:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['stopWatchService.secondsElapsed', 'stopWatchService.minutesElapsed', 'stopWatchService.colon'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope){
    scope.secondsElapsed = newValues[0];
    scope.minutesElapsed = newValues[1];
    scope.colon = newValues[2];
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to deep watch `stopWatchService` instead? For deep watch group i had provided an answer earlier, probably it might help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956768/how-to-watch-more-than-one-collection-in-angular/25960854#25960854

Comment: In your second snippet `$scope.timers` holds only values of the elapsed times at that point, meaning it is array of primitive, later changes in the variables will not be available there, and hence watch function will not run as every evaluation of watch will yield the same result.. What about `$scope.$watchGroup($scope.timers, function(...`. Remember that `watchGroup` does not do a deep watch...

Comment: Thanks for that. So how should I declare my array instead? I'm not sure how to pass the variables itself rather than the values.

Comment: What happens when you do `$scope.$watchGroup($scope.timers` The reason being by providing `[$scope.timers]` to watch group you are asking it to track array of arrays, which it probably wont.. instead you just need to pass timers array?

Comment: Same problem. Still doesn't seem to update

Comment: Can you prepare a plnkr. But ideally you just need a watch on `stopWatchService` right? or a deep watch on array of stopWatchServices ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `$watchCollection` ?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection

Comment: Yes, I have. Maybe, I'm using it wrong, but it didn't update the scope variables as I wanted it to.
I've edited my question to include my attempt with $watchCollection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check $watchGroup, I think is exactly your problem, pass an array as first param, right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `$scope.timers` into an array, it is already one.

`$scope.$watchGroup($scope.timers, ...)` instead of `$scope.$watchGroup([$scope.timers], ...)`