# Reference and collection watches in a single watch in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

In an Angular 1.3 application I've a scope object (simplified) like this:

```
$scope.data = {
    myObject = {
        id = 0
        someItems = [
            {
                id = 0, 
                title = foo
            },
            {
                id = 0, 
                title = foo
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My real object contains much more properties and also circular references.

I need a watch which is called if either `data.myObject` is a new object assigned, the value of `data.myObject.id` changes, or an item is added or removed from `myObject.someItems`.

This can be achieved with two watches together:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(
    ['data.myObject', 'data.myObject.id'],
    function () {
        doSomething();
    }
);
$scope.$watchCollection(
    'data.myObject.someItems',
    function () {
        doSomething();
    }
);
```

The problem with this approach is that if `data.myObject` changes `doSomething`is called twice. Therefore I'm looking for a way to handle this in a single `watch`.

An equality watch doesn't seem to be suitable since there are a lot of other properties on the object which don't need to be watched. A solution like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712888/how-to-use-a-watchgroup-with-object-equality-or-deep-watch-the-properties-in-th#answer-25713285) also doesn't work since my object contains circular references.

**Update**
Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7ch0hdf/). Clicking on "Change 1", "Change 2" and "Change 3" should all result in a single alert. Currently clicking on "Change 1" gives two alerts.

Comment: "The problem with this approach is that if data.myObject changes doSomethingis called twice" - the $watchGroup callback function has 3 arguments - newValues, oldValues, scope  (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). When it's called twice, what are the values? Is it called with same values twice? Also I guess JSFiddle would help people to help you.

Comment: Couldn't you just watch `data.myObject`?

Comment: @DonJuwe Adding an equality watch on `data.myObject` unfortunately is no option since my object contains much unrelated properties and circular references  (which would result in exceptions)

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to revise the way the object is built, the fact that the things become tricky and fight the framework indicates that something went wrong in the design.

Comment: The object is a breeze.js entity which always contain circular references. Therefore there's no way to getting rid of them easily without either deciding not to use breeze.js or write a layer on top which creates objects without the circular references.

Comment: @tiblu I created a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u7ch0hdf/)

Comment: you most certainly *can* use breeze and not have circular references.  there is an article that discusses this (written for KO but still applicable), http://breeze.github.io/doc-cool-breezes/knockout-circular-refs.html.  The takeaway here is to construct a query using a select clause that names just the property values you need.

Comment: Projections are a way to getting rid of circular references, but it has its own drawbacks which are not working in my case (eg. entities are not cached)