# Function in AngularJS not calling to $WatchGroup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function that is activated when a button is pressed, and it removes an object from an array:

```
$scope.remove = function (index) {
    //$scope.myPeople.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.myPeople.splice(index, 1);
    console.log($scope.myPeople);
}
```

And in my `$scop.$watchGroup` I have this:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['metric.value', 'startDate.value', 'endDate.value', 'myPeople', 'remove'], function () {
angular.forEach($scope.myPeople, function (key) {
   peopleArray = peopleArray.concat(key.screenName + ",");
});
   peopleArray = peopleArray.slice(0, -1);
   peopleArray = peopleArray.concat("}");
});
```

But for some reason, when I delete something from the list, `$watchGroup` doesn't seem to be listening to it...

Here is the html code that I used in the call, maybe it helps

```js
<a  ng-click="remove($index)"
value="{{person}}" type="button"style="color:red">
<i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

I'm still trying this without success...

```
    $scope.$watchCollection('[myPeople]', function () {
    $scope.dataPie.length = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.myPeople, function (value) {

        $scope.dataPie.push({
            "key": value.name,
            "y": value.followerCount
        });
    });

});
```

But it does not trigger when this function is invoked!

```
$scope.remove = function (index) {
    $scope.myPeople.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.apply;
}
```

Any clue?!?

Comment: Did you try $scope.$apply() after deleting the element?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's not calling it? Have you put a breakpoint inside the $watchGroup?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin yes, but still not working

Comment: @Katana24 I've tryed with debugger; and it does not go inside the function. It looks like it does not recognice splice() as a change in myPeople scope or something...

Comment: @MiguelXoelGarcia, can you provide sample plunkr that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Grundy I've made [this one](http://plnkr.co/edit/lnIVJNeJ7auLzafHlCo8?p=preview). It's not pretty good, but if you check the console you can see the $digest loop error. I made it 'work' but now I get the digest problem... Hope it helps. It gets the data from my localhost, so it's kind of hard to reproduce in a plunkr.

Comment: @MiguelXoelGarcia, is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/9A0s5i8RWKeNJniVnpka?p=preview) what you try do?

Comment: @Grundy yes! What Did you actually changed? And could you tell me (as shown in the question) how would you use watch collection for more than one value watched? Thanks!

Comment: @MiguelXoelGarcia, just use watchCollection as  in answer A.Sharma. Can you change this sample to add sample for your another values to watch?

Comment: @Grundy [Here] (http://plnkr.co/edit/x0LiBtd9xfgFozQqOk3R?p=preview), there you go. Check out how when watching more than one thing, the scope doesn't to recognice that you are splicing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) with third argument `true` and custom function that return object for watching, for example

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(scope){
      return [scope.myPeople, $scope.$eval('metric.value')];
    }, 
    function() {
        ...
    },
    true
);
```

Sample

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ProfileController', function($scope) {

  $scope.myPeople = [{
    name: '1',
    followerCount: 1
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    followerCount: 2
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    followerCount: 3
  },
  {
    name: '4',
    followerCount: 4
  }];
  
  $scope.remove = function(index) {
    $scope.myPeople.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.dataPie = [];
  
  $scope.$watch(
    function(scope){
      return [scope.myPeople, $scope.$eval('metric.value')];
    }, function() {
    $scope.dataPie.length = 0;
console.log("test");
    angular.forEach($scope.myPeople, function(value) {
      $scope.dataPie.push({
        "key": value.name,
        "y": value.followerCount
      });
    });

  },true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" class="table-responsive" ng-controller="ProfileController">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in myPeople | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
          <td><img class="img-rounded" ng-src="{{person.profileImageUrl}}"></td>
          <td>{{person.name}}</td>
          <td>
            <a ng-click="remove($index)" value="{{person}}" type="button" style="color:red">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Remover</a>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    {{dataPie}}
<br><br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="metric.value" value="11"> valueOne <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="metric.value" value="12"> valueTwo <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="metric.value" value="13"> valueThree <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </label>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`watchGroup` doesn't do a deep scan of the array contents

You may want to use the `$watchCollection` instead of `$watchGroup`.

See the Angular Docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

An array is an indexed collection as well as being an object, which is why the `$watchCollection` can be used:

**Angular Code**

```
$scope.remove = function(index) {
 $scope.myPeople.splice(index, 1);
};


$scope.$watchCollection('myPeople', function(newPeople, oldPeople) {
 console.log(newPeople);
});
```

Here is a Plunker showing the code in action: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/A2STZcWtWYFSdqYFFNfy?p=preview)

Comment: Not valid, I have more things that need to be watched in the same $watch function, not only 'myPeople'. See my code in the question

Comment: Well the issue your experiencing is that `watchGroup` doesn't do a deep scan of the array contents. For example, instead of splicing the array, try to assign it to a completely different value (ie. "Hello World"), and it will work. You will need to create your own watcher. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712888/how-to-use-a-watchgroup-with-object-equality-or-deep-watch-the-properties-in-th#answer-25713285

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

`$scope.myPeople.splice(index, 1);`

With

`$scope.myPeople = $scope.myPeople.slice(0).splice(index, 1);`

You don't need an additional $watch.

Comment: `splice` return items that was removed, so after this `$scope.myPeople = $scope.myPeople.slice(0).splice(index, 1);`, `$scope.myPeople` would be array with just one element